# Importing font causes incorrect layout

Tags: css, html, import, overflow

First of all, this is my first post here ever, so my apologies if I did anything wrong.

To my problem:
A section has a `width: 100%` and `overflow-x: scroll`. 
If I import the font 'Open Sans' from google the section suddenly get's an increased width of more than 100% and no content will thus overflow it.
The problem seems to be solved by either removing the import or giving main `display: block` instead of `display: table`.

https://jsfiddle.net/ehvpehb6/

Once again, in the fiddle you can't scroll in the section itself. But if you either remove the external resource or change the `display` property for main, you can.

This brings us to my question: What causes this? Why is it that `display: table` and the import clash with one another?

**EDIT:** The issue with the font only appears to be in Chrome, when I tried it in Firefox the import did not cause any problems.

[Image explaining it further](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEiFT.jpg)

As @colonelclick suggested importing the font in the CSS will fix the problem.. but not when I create a document on my computer and testing it that way. If I import the font in the `<head>` it casues the issue aswell.

My html ended up looking like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Goot pruject</title>

  <!-- Either this... -->
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  <style>
    /* ...Or this. Both with the same result.
 @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
    */
    main {
      width: 100%;
      display: table;
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    }
    section {
      width: 100%;
      height: 230px;
      overflow-y: hidden;
      overflow-x: scroll;
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
    main figure {
      display: inline-block;
      width: auto;
      margin-right: 30px;
      height: inherit;
      border: 1px solid #b2b2b2;
    }
    main figure img {
      width: inherit;
      height: inherit;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <section>
      <figure>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/155x230" />
      </figure>
      <figure>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/155x230" />
      </figure>
      <figure>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/155x230" />
      </figure>
      <figure>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/155x230" />
      </figure>
      <figure>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/155x230" />
      </figure>
      <figure>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/155x230" />
      </figure>
      <figure>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/155x230" />
      </figure>
      <figure>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/155x230" />
      </figure>
      <figure>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/155x230" />
      </figure>
      <figure>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/155x230" />
      </figure>
      <figure>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/155x230" />
      </figure>
    </section>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

The burning question is WHY an import of a font would change the way the layout works.

Comment: Please include any relevant code in your question, preferably in a Stack Snippet.

Comment: I dont see a problem.

Comment: All of the relevant code can be found in the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Your fiddle is setup incorrectly.

You have added this as an external resource but this is not a link to an external file, this is HTML code.

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

There are several ways you could fix this. **They all require removing the existing external resource, which is not a correct external resource string.** I tested all four of these solutions, and the problem goes away in Chrome after you fix the error in your fiddle.

1. Place the link code in the HTML of your fiddle.

> https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans'
>   rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

2. Use just the font URL as an external resource.

> https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans

3. Use the import command from google fonts in the css of your fiddle.

> @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);

4. Use the js font loader from google in the js portion of your fiddle. (Available at https://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Open+Sans)

Comment: Interesting. If I imported the font in the CSS in the fiddle, it worked. I then created a html file on my computer and tried to import it the same way there. That did not work. I also tried importing it with `<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>` in the `<head>`, this did not work either. What's even more strange is that about 50% of the times I refreshed the page it would work and 50% of the time it would not. Here is a paste of how my .html file looked http://pastebin.com/BbQF4fAw

Comment: I tried pasting your code into a file on my desktop and after I few tries I did see the scrollbar every time. Usually when something like that is inconsistent I think of caching issues and double check with incognito mode. Not sure if that applies here.